# TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

```
import os   
from selenium import webdriver
import time    
from linkedin_scraper import actions    
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()    
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)    
email = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_USER")    
password = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_PASSWORD")

actions.login(driver, email, password) # if email and password isnt given, it'll prompt in terminal
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/company/biorasi-llc/about/')

_ = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'section')))

time.sleep(3)    
grid = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("section")[3]
about_us = grid.find_elements_by_tag_name("p")[0].text.strip()

print(about_us)
```

**This is my code for scraping about_us data of a company and it works but sometimes I get an error like:**

TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
 17 email = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_USER")
 18 password = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_PASSWORD")
```

---> 19 actions.login(driver, email, password) # if email and password isnt given, it'll prompt in terminal

```
 20 driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/company/biorasi-llc/about/')
 21 _ = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'section')))
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\linkedin_scraper\actions.py in login(driver, email, password)

```
 28   password_elem.submit()
 29
```

---> 30   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "profile-nav-item")))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)

```
 78             if time.time() > end_time:
 79                 break
```

---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
81
82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:

Someone, please help how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your timeout is too short (3 seconds) so before the page is fully loaded, it reaches timeout threshold. Try raising it to 5-10 seconds in line 21.

```py
TIMEOUT = 10
 _ = WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'section')))
```

Here's some tips to improve your code:

- You're already using fluent wait (`WebDriverWait`), try to minimize using `time.sleep` if possible. `WebDriverWait` will stop waiting & return your element, so time will be saved.
- Finding element via tag name & locate it by ordinal (in this case, 4th section tag) is a bad idea. Will break if the site adds more section. Try using better XPATH, here's my code, I have not tested but I think it will work just fine.

```py
import os   
from selenium import webdriver
import time    
from linkedin_scraper import actions    
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()    
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)    
email = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_USER")    
password = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_PASSWORD")

actions.login(driver, email, password) # if email and password isnt given, it'll prompt in terminal
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/company/biorasi-llc/about/')

# directly finds paragraph, removed time.sleep
paragraph_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//section//h4/..//p')))
about_us = paragraph_elem.text.strip()

print(about_us)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error and this happens only sometimes. Sometimes it works and sometimes getting this TimeoutException error.

Comment: I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the timeout to 15 seconds? Your network might not be fast enough to load the page in 5 seconds. I updated the script to 15 seconds, have a try.

Comment: Yup, I tried 15,30,50 also, it's still not working.

Comment: Maybe linkedin is sending PIN on your email and waiting for you to insert it.